# HBase HDFS zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Now I am learning about HBase. I set up my HBase Cluster and Hadoop Cluster like this:

```
server1: Namenode HMaster
server2: datanode1 RegionServer1 HQuorumPeer
Server3: datanode2 RegionServer2 HQuorumPeer
Server4: datanode3 RegionServer3 HQuorumPeer
```

I have several question about HBase cluster:

```
1: All RegionServers must be in the Hadoop Cluster so it can use HDFS to store 
   data, even though it will store data into local file system, right?
2: What does RegionServer do? Does the HMaster give the job to all RegionServeres 
   and let them running parallel, like tasktracker in datanode? 
3: What does zookeeper do? Do I need to setup zookeeper in all RegionServers 
   nodes and the master node? 
4: It is related to #3. I know HBase uses zookeeper to recovery once regionServer 
   is down. How does it specific work?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**All RegionServers must be in the Hadoop Cluster so it can use HDFS to store 
   data, even though it will store data into local file system, right?**

Yes. RegionServers are the daemons that are responsible for storing data in a HBase cluster. You store data in HBase tables which are spread over many regions on several RegionServers across the cluster. Although data goes into the RegionServers, it actually gets stored inside HDFS. But if you are on a standalone setup HDFS is not used. The data gets stored directly in the local FS. It is analogous to any DB and FS. Take MSQL and ext3 for example. And yes, all the HDFS data is stored on your disk in reality. You cannot see it directly though.

**What does RegionServer do? Does the HMaster give the job to all RegionServeres 
   and let them running parallel, like tasktracker in datanode?**

As specified in the comment above RegionServer is the daemon that actually stores data in a HBase cluster. I'm sorry I didn't quite get the second part of this question. what do you mean by **like tasktracker in datanode**? In a HBase cluster HMaster is the daemon which is responsible for monitoring all RegionServer instances in the cluster, and is the interface for all metadata changes. Its job is monitoring and management. Regionservers don't run any job like TaskTrackers do. They just store data and are responsible for stuff like serving and managing regions.

**What does zookeeper do? Do I need to setup zookeeper in all RegionServers 
   nodes and the master node?**

Zookeeper is the guy who coordinates everything behind the curtains. It is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services. A distributed HBase setup depends on a running ZooKeeper cluster. All participating nodes and clients need to be able to access the running ZooKeeper ensemble. HBase by default manages a ZooKeeper cluster. It gets started and stopped as part of the HBase start/stop process. But, you can also manage the ZooKeeper ensemble independent of HBase and just point HBase at the cluster it should use. You don't have to have Zookeepers running on all the nodes. Just decide some number which suits your cluster. One thing to note here is that you should always use an **odd** number of Zookeepers.

**It is related to #3. I know HBase uses zookeeper to recovery once regionServer 
   is down. How does it specific work?**

Each RegionServer is connected to ZooKeeper, and the master watches these connections. ZooKeeper manages a heartbeat with a timeout. So, on a timeout, the HMaster declares the region server as dead, and starts the recovery process. Following things happen during the recovery process :

- **Identifying that a node is down :** a node can cease to respond simply because it is overloaded or as well because it is dead.
- **Recovering the writes in progress :** that’s reading the commit log and recovering the edits that were not flushed.
- **Reassigning the regions :** the region server was previously handling a set of regions. This set must be reallocated to other region servers, depending on their respective workload.

The process is actually a bit more involved. You can find more on this **[here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/introduction-to-hbase-mean-time-to-recover-mttr/)**. I would also suggest you to go through the book HBase The Definitive Guide by Lars in order to get some grip on HBase.

HTH

Comment: wow~You are really a excellent professor. You give me lots of details and useful information. Thank you so much. I have only one question about it: if I only set up HQuorumPeer in Server2; when server3 is down, will zookeeper know that?

Comment: Or I just need to set up only one zookeeper in hbase.zookeeper.quorum?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm still in the learning phase just like you :). Yes, it knows about all the servers.

Comment: It totally depends on your needs. But its good to have some number greater than 1. For a small cluster 3 should be OK.

Comment: One small suggestion. Since you are just starting with HBase use the ZK which comes with HBase and get yourself familiar with everything properly. Once you are comfortable create a separate ZK cluster with 3 or more nodes and use it with your cluster.

Comment: Thank you, Tariq. The reason why the number of zookeeper nodes is usually more than 1 is just more safety, right? But only one also does work.

Comment: Yes. One ZK would serve the purpose.

Comment: Great explanation, but just a note. It is not required to use always an odd number of Zookeepers, just recommended. "run an odd number of machines. In ZooKeeper, an even number of peers is supported, but it is normally not used"

Comment: why we are creating instances